# English dictionary needed for a word game

Tags: dictionary, spelling

I'm looking for a way to include a full blown English dictionary in an iPhone app (a word game), the database must be able to include all conjugation possibilities for verbs, must include singular and plural spellings. So my app can query the database to check if the spelling is correct.

Is there a free or commercial database that would include those data?

Comment: You could use a `NSSpellChecker`.

Comment: Is there a way to upvote the Edit Summary?  ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [UITextChecker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextChecker_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for spell-checking.

Regarding a dictionary, when I built an iOS dictionary library sometime ago ([www.lexicontext.com](http://www.lexicontext.com/)) I used WordNet. WordNet contains a lot of interesting semantic info ...

Answer (score 1):

NSSpellChecker is your easiest option, but it might be more complete to use the online Scrabble official dictionary as well and check it against both (only one match required.)

You could do a web-service request using http://www.hasbro.com/scrabble/en_US/search.cfm

Comment: I forgot to mention that one of the constraint I have, is to have the full database available on the device, I don't want to query any server in the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

```
http://www.a2zwordfinder.com/cgi-bin/scrabble.cgi?Letters=&Pattern=______&MatchType=Exactly&MinLetters=3&SortBy=Alpha&SearchType=Scrabble
```

Change min letters to get different results

Answer (score 0):

The best place to find a database for a spell-checker is probably a free text processing application. So, I'd try with Open Office version of Word. Download it, install it and simply find the dictionary file.

Open Office is licensed under LGPL, so it should be fine, just check if the licence covers the data as well (i.e. the dictionary file).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this English corpus helps: http://www.wordfrequency.info/free.asp